CANbus fault issue
Ford Crown Vic

Code b2477 in instrument cluster
Code u1262 in instrument cluster
Code U1900-20 in IC and ABS modules

Vehicle shut off and was very hard to start and had a low stumbling idle. Would start and immediately shut off. Vehicle eventually sustained idle and drive as normal after pumping throttle pedal.
AT OBD DLC:

resistance between CAN-HI and CAN-LO is 60 ohms. Disconnecting module with one terminating resistor (ABS MODULE) resistance increases to 120ohms as expected. Same with Instrument Cluster (the other module with a terminating resistor)

resistance between CAN-HI and GND is only 600 ohms, same for CAN-LO. When ABS module is disconnected resistance between CAN HI and GND increases to 7K ohms. Same for CAN Lo.


Unsure if that is a normal reading for resistance from bus to ground. Please advise

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

What year? Was the pcm replaced? Condition of wiring? Before chasing canbus issues, is this carburetor, throttle body injector or EFI system? Was spark tested? Fuel pressure tested?  The following are definitions of each error code. One repair shop, SMA, is featured a youtube description of error code U1900; https://www.autocodes.com/u1900_ford.html. He's an expert's expert.  The other codes, https://www.autocodes.com/b2477_ford.html and https://www.autocodes.com/u1262_ford.html, may help but keep in mind all three errors may be falsely generated from possible volage issues; battery, main power and ground connections, alternator and drive belt.
